# NSOutlineView won't reload data on keydown, but updates on focus

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I've been trying to figure this issue out for the last couple of hours with a lot of searching involved and watching videos.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Summary**: A simple window allowing me to move a message from my inbox to any of my many mail folders. As I type the name of the mail folder I'm looking for, the outline view should automatically refresh only displaying the ones with the matching text - think MsgFiler if you know it.

- Type text in text box
- As I type each letter, I want the NSOutlineView to update it's data to have less and less folders that match my input text. (At the moment, my test just adds a "Test Mailbox" into the NSOutlineView

**Current result**:

- Type text in text box
- Nothing happens
- Click the NSOutlineView, the view gets updated

## TextfieldDelegate.m:

```
#import "TextFieldDelegate.h"
#import "OutlineViewController.h"
#import "GetMailDatasource.h"

@implementation TextFieldDelegate

@synthesize testLabel;

- (void) controlTextDidChange :(NSNotification *) sender {
  NSTextField *changedField = [sender object];
  NSLog(@"in control text did change");

  //Just some text code to see the change when text does change
  NSString *text = [changedField stringValue];
  [testLabel setStringValue:text];

  NSLog(@"changed the label and creating the data now");

  OutlineViewController *vc = [[OutlineViewController alloc] init];
  [vc refreshTheData:sender];
  [vc.outlineView reloadData];
  [vc release];
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
  NSLog(@"in end editting");
  return;
}

@end
```

## OutlineViewController.m

```
#import "OutlineViewController.h"
#import "GetMailDatasource.h"

@implementation OutlineViewController

- (id) init {

  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _mailboxes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (myMailboxes != nil) {
        _mailboxes = myMailboxes;
    } else {
        GetMailDatasource *mailDatasource = [[GetMailDatasource alloc] init];
        [mailDatasource createFakeData];
        _mailboxes = myMailboxes;
    }
  }

  NSLog(@"inited outline view controller");
  return self;
}

- (IBAction) refreshTheData : (id) sender {

  NSLog(@"in refreshTheData");

  Mailbox *m = [self.outlineView itemAtRow:[self.outlineView selectedRow]];
  if (m)
     [m addChild:[[Mailbox alloc] init]];
  else
      [self.mailboxes addObject:[[Mailbox alloc] init]];

  NSLog(@"running reloadData");
  [self.outlineView reloadData];
}

#I know these work, but providing them for completeness
#pragma mark NSOutlineView Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    return !item ? [self.mailboxes count] : [[ item children] count ];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return !item ? YES : [[item children ] count] != 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    return !item ? [self.mailboxes objectAtIndex:index] : [[item children] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    return [item name];
}

@end
```

I do have a separate "Test Button" that I added on the interface just to try out and I've bound it's "Sent action" directly to the "refreshTheData" function on the OutlineViewController and that works without a hitch.  Adds the new item in the NSOutlineView and it updates immediately.

I'm not sure what else is required to try to figure out where the problem lies... Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance every time controlTextDidChange. So you change the settings of this OutlineViewController and than release it.

Instead of this you should use the outline view on screen.

Comment: How would I use the outline view on screen? I've tried different ways to do this, but when I create a property for the NSOutlineView in my TextFieldDelegate.h and try to do something like [outlineView refreshTheData], I get the message "outlineView may not respond to refreshTheData", any thoughts?

Comment: Just to add, in my TextFieldDelegate.h, I reference the property as such:

Comment: @property (retain) IBOutlet NSOutlineView *outlineView; (hit enter too soon)

Comment: You still can use your outline view *controller*. But you should not instantiate it in the code each time controlTextDidChange: runs. Probably you want to instantiate it in the ib and connect it with an outlet or create an instance in code (TextDelegate) one time and assign it to a property.

Comment: Thanks @amin-negm-awad but I tried a couple of things, pulling the instantiation of OutlineViewController from my method into the TextFieldDelegate.m only cause the application to go into an infinite loop somewhere in Apple code after a couple of clicks of my test button.
As for instantiating in the IB (I didn't mention this was my first time working in xcode), how would I do that? I have my NSOutlineView named in the IB and if I ctrl-drag-drop the TextFieldDelegate onto the OutlineView, I can associate it as an outlet but that breaks things even worse, any other thoughts?

Comment: As I said you have to distinguish between the outline view and the outline view controller. You can create an instance in ib by dropping an object into the sidebar and setting its class to whatever you want. But I think that you should learn some basic abilities with a tutorial or a book. Actually it sound like try & error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.

So, I already had the outline view in IB and an object for the OutlineViewController in IB.  I even tried referencing the new method "refreshTheData" in my controller by using the OutlineView object I had associated to my TextFieldDelegate.  That's where I was wrong.

What I needed to do was associate the OutlineViewController itself to my TextFieldDelegate, then I could call "refreshTheData" with the appropriate links in the IB interface.

So, finally, the code looks like this, changes highlighted like this -->:

## TextFieldDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
--> #import "OutlineViewController.h"

@interface TextFieldDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet OutlineViewController *outlineView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextField * testLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextField * userInput;

- (IBAction) controlTextDidChange :(id) sender;
```

@end

And this now allows TextFieldDelegate.m's code, get recognised:

```
- (void) controlTextDidChange :(NSNotification *) sender {
    NSTextField *changedField = [sender object];

    NSString *text = [changedField stringValue];
    [testLabel setStringValue:text];

    --> [outlineView refreshTheData:sender];
}
```

The highlighted line always suggested that it could not recognise that method because I was trying to use it on the actual NSOutlineView item, not it's delegate where I created the method.  I had thought that by hooking up the delegate to the NSOutlineView, they would either become one and the same, or that the method would be find via transitivity sort of.

Thanks for the pointers @Amin, it helped me get there in the end.